# tooltip shows tz.locale for time data. How can I format tooltip to use the same time (utc) from the dataframe

Tags: pandas, altair

I'm trying to display the utc time from a pd dataframe
inside tooltip but it's always showing localtime in the browser.

with below code :

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2]})
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'local': ['2018-01-01T09:00:00', '2018-01-01T10:00:00', '2018-01-01T14:00:00'],
    'utc': ['2018-01-01T09:00:00Z', '2018-01-01T10:00:00Z', \
        '2018-01-01T14:00:00Z']
})


df['utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['utc'], utc=True)
df['local'] = pd.to_datetime(df['local'], utc=False)
df['iso'] = df['utc'].apply(lambda x: x.isoformat())

dia1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_rule().encode(
    x=alt.X('utchoursminutes(utc)', type='temporal'),
    y=alt.Y('utchoursminutes(utc)', type='temporal'),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip(field="utc",
                    type="temporal",
                    title="utc",
                    format="%Y-%m-%dT:%H:%M:%S",
                    formatType="time")
    ],
).interactive()
```

X Axis is showing the same time from the dataframe (utc) regardless from which tz the
browser is used. Which is desired.

[image]

But the tooltip is always showing the locale time.
E.g. 7 PM from Tokyo but 11 PM from Berlin. How can I format the time series that it
displays the original time from dataframe within the tooltip box?
Or is there any format option possible to specify inside the tooltip?

Thx

Comment: The behavior seems to be different in browsers that support ES6; it seems that browsers that support ES6 treat time strings without a trailing Z as local time. See here for [details](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/times_and_dates.html). There is also a script to check if it is supported or not.

Comment: Thx, I have seen this already. But even appending a 'Z' seems not to solve it.
I will do some further testing.

Comment: This is a bug in Vega-Lite specific to UTC time formats in tooltip labels; you can see the issue here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7185

Comment: thx a lot jakevdp - I appreciate your great efforts in contribution to altair related topics

Comment: would it possible to implement something in altair tooltip as in vega light:
"scale": {"type": "utc"} ?